# Python basic menu, created a "loop". Is this bad?

Tags: python, loops, menu

I wrote a basic user interface in python, But I have a question. Here is the code:

```
def mainUI():
  options=["doSomething","exit"]
  index=0
  print options[index]
  command=raw_input("Give a command: ")
  while True:
    if command="select":
      print "you selected ",options[index]
    elif command="up":
      index=UIListIndexIncrease(index,len(options))
      print options[index]
      command=raw_input("Give a command: ")
    elif command="down":
      index=UIListIndexDecrease(index)
      print options[index]
      command=raw_input("Give a command: ")
    time.sleep(0.25)

def mainDispatch(index):
  if index==0:
    yesOrNoMenu(aFunctionThatDoesSomething)
  elif index==1:
    exitProgram()


def aFunctionThatDoesSomething():
  ...
  mainUI()


def yesOrNoMenu(function,*opargs):   #<------ this function never exits
  index=0
  options=["are you sure? \n [no] yes","are you sure? \n no [yes]"]
  print options[index]
  x=raw_input("give a command: ")
  while True:
    if x=="select":
      dispatchYesNo(index,function,*opargs)  #<--------- the function is passed to the dispatch function and is executed there, the function returns to MainUI().
                                             #Then it goes from the dispatch back to the main function
      break    # <--------------------
    if x=="up":
      index=UIListIndexDecrease(index)    
      print options[index]
      x=raw_input("give a command: ")
    if x=="down":
      index=UIListIndexIncrease(index,len(options))
      print options[index]
      x=raw_input("give a command: ")
    time.sleep(0.25)
  # all the code here is executed at the end, when the script ends


def dispatchYesNo(index,function,*opargs):
  if index == 0:
     mainUI()
  elif index == 1:
     function(*opargs)
```

By pointing back to the mainUI() from the function aFunctionThatDoesSomething(), we create a **"loop"**. We started in mainUI(), we did something and now we're back in mainUI().
I'm not sure if this is a problem, but by doing so, the yesOrNoMenu never exits and we keep on **"nesting functioncalls"** inside the first yesOrNoMenu call.
By doing so, the stacktrace can become pretty big.

```
File "./transfer.py", line 383, in <module>
    main()
  File "./transfer.py", line 369, in main
    mainUI()
  File "./transfer.py", line 240, in mainUI
    mainDispatch(index)
  File "./transfer.py", line 227, in mainDispatch
    aFunctionThatDoesSomething()
  File "./transfer.py", line 286, in aFunctionThatDoesSomething
    yesOrNoMenu(aFunctionThatDoesSomething)
  File "./transfer.py", line 310, in yesOrNoMenu
    dispatchYesNo(index,function,*opargs)
  File "./transfer.py", line 324, in dispatchYesNo
    mainUI()
  File "./transfer.py", line 240, in mainUI
    mainDispatch(index)
  File "./transfer.py", line 227, in mainDispatch
    aFunctionThatDoesSomething()
  File "./transfer.py", line 286, in aFunctionThatDoesSomething
    yesOrNoMenu(aFunctionThatDoesSomething)
  File "./transfer.py", line 310, in yesOrNoMenu
    dispatchYesNo(index,function,*opargs)
  File "./transfer.py", line 324, in dispatchYesNo
    mainUI()
  File "./transfer.py", line 240, in mainUI
    mainDispatch(index)
  File "./transfer.py", line 227, in mainDispatch
    aFunctionThatDoesSomething()
  File "./transfer.py", line 286, in aFunctionThatDoesSomething
    yesOrNoMenu(aFunctionThatDoesSomething)
  File "./transfer.py", line 310, in yesOrNoMenu
    dispatchYesNo(index,function,*opargs)
  File "./transfer.py", line 324, in dispatchYesNo
    mainUI()
  File "./transfer.py", line 240, in mainUI
```

I don't know if this is bad code or if this is normal. Can anyone help me with this? 
thanks

Comment: Yes, long stack traces are bad. Once you hit the maximum recursion limit (usually 1000 nested functions), Python crashes with a `RuntimeError`. (I'm posting this as a comment and not an answer because I don't have any advice for fixing your code in particular)

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `mainUI()` call within `aFunctionThatDoesSomething`? `mainUI` already loops forever due to its `while True:`, so the program should continue running without that call anyway.

Comment: Tried it. It worked. You sir are my hero :). You should post it as a reply so I can mark it ;)

Comment: I'm glad my lucky guess was useful :-)

Comment: i'd also suggest that you move your three "command=raw_input("Give a command: ")" lines into a single line at the beginning of your while loop, wont make any difference to the running of it, but keeps your code that bit simpler and neater

Comment: You are completely right. :). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is potentially bad practice. Python has a maximum recursion limit; once your stack trace has a thousand functions, your program will crash with a `RuntimeError`.

I suggest modifying `aFunctionThatDoesSomething` so that it doesn't call `mainUI`. the main function has a `while True:` loop anyway, so it should naturally repeat itself once `aFunction` completes, even if you don't call it explicitly.